# Probability of random and uniformly distributed variable

Tags: probability

Assuming there is a whole blueberry pie, how can I calculate the probability of a person eating half of it given that the size of the eaten pie slice is random and uniformly distributed? Would it be 1/2?

Answer (score 3):

Because the uniform distribution is continuous, the probability of the person eating *exactly* half is zero. The probability of eating *at least* half is $1/2$, as you said.

Comment: Then how can I calculate the probability that two people sequentially ate the whole pie, but each had one half?